# What's the opposite of inList in my cakePHP model?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

`inList` states that your array should contain a certain string value.
I'm looking for a rule that will **exclude** certain values for names in my model.

The following code states that the name should be Bob, Bobbie or Bobzilla:

```
'name'  => array(
    'rule' => array('inList', array('Bob', 'Bobbie', 'Bobzilla')),
    'message' => 'Stop it Bob!'
),
```

I need the user to be **unable** to enter any of these names. To me it seems as if `inList` should be `notInList`.
I've tried many ways but none of them lead me to Rome.

If you could help me that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a notInList in 2.x, like you said. You'll have to create your own validation rule, as shown here: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: Thank you! I'm working on that right now. I just figured there would be an _easier/less code_ way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I was able to come up with:

```
public function itsBob($check) {  
    $bobArr = ['Bob', 'Bobbie', 'Bobzilla'];

    if (!in_array($check['name'], bobArr) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

With the following lines in the $validation:

```
'name' => array(
    'rule' => array('itsBob'),
    'message' => 'Stop it bob!'
),
```

`itsBob` literally does the opposite of `inList`.

Comment: Feel free to call the function `outList($check)` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PHP in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php) function
something like

```
if (!in_array(ENTERED_NAME,YOUR ARRAY)) {

}
```